# Creating a dictionary from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key, keyvaluepair

I am trying to create a sort of 'dict of dicts'.  The 1st level dictionary is a word-frequency key-value pair.  Created by the for-loop below, 'cleaned_words_string' is the string that holds the text I am analyzing and is unique to each store.

```
        stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

        word_tokens = word_tokenize(cleaned_word_string)

        filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]

        filtered_sentence = []

        for w in word_tokens:
            if w.lower() not in stop_words:
                filtered_sentence.append(w)

        fw_freq = nltk.FreqDist(filtered_sentence).most_common()

        freq_dict = dict(fw_freq)
```

How can I modify this code such that each individual 'storename' gets attached to its freq_dict?

Something like:

```
Store_dict = {storename: freq_dict}
```

such that the output would be:

Store_dict {'Target': freq_dict, 'WalMart':freq_dct , etc.}

Comment: Doesn't `{"Target" : freq_dict}` work?

Comment: Well 'store1': 'door: 1', 'sound: 2', etc.

Comment: I need some way to identify which dictionary belongs to which store

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify: {"Target": freq_dict} does get me to where I need to go - how can I pass the variable 'store' into that syntax such that it becomes {"Target": freq_dict}, {"Shopko": freq_dict}, etc, based on the value I am passing into 'store'

Answer (score 0):

```
// I suppose your store of sentences is in this format
store = {'store_name': cleaned_word_string}


store_dict = {}
for store_name in store:
    store_dict[store_name] = get_freq_dict(store_dict[store_name])


def get_freq_dict(cleaned_word_string):

    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(cleaned_word_string)
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]
    fw_freq = nltk.FreqDist(filtered_sentence).most_common()
    freq_dict = dict(fw_freq)
    return freq_dict
```